# How to make functions that draw lines in canvas (tkinter 3.x) properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a program that draws a line(you decide where is the beggining and end of it with the sliders/scales), problem is im getting these errors(That i wish i understood) when i press the psy Button(code below the errors) :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python351\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Koteu/PycharmProjects/guji/fsd.py", line 23, in creat
    cans.create_line(ar1,ar2,br1,br2)
  File "C:\python351\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2331, in create_line
    return self._create('line', args, kw)
  File "C:\python351\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2319, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance ".14855536.14855504"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

anyways, the code :

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
app=Frame(root)

root.geometry("1200x1200")
ar1 = Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)
ar2= Scale(app,from_=0,to=600,deafultvar=0)#app instead of root because the button for unknown to me reason 
#wouldn't appear in GUI otherwise
br1= Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)
br2= Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)





cans = Canvas(root,width = 500,height = 500)

cans.create_line(600,50,0,50) #This has nothing to do with the actual program by my understanding


def creat():
    cans.create_line(ar1,ar2,br1,br2)#< this is what causes the problem i don't understand 


psy=Button(root,command=creat,text="karole")
psy.pack()
cans.pack()
ar1.pack()
ar2.pack()
br1.pack()
br2.pack()

mainloop()
```

also, if that helps, im using py345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cans.create_line(x0, y0, ...) takes an even number of integer coordinates as positional args.  You passed widgets, which were turned into their string identifiers.  In `".14855536.14855504"`, `'.'` represents root, `'14855536'` is the canvas, and `'14855504'` is the scale `ar1`.  Instead you need to use the `.get()` method on the scales to get their integer values.  The following works.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.geometry("1200x1200")
ar1 = Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)
ar2= Scale(root,from_=0, to=600)
br1= Scale(root,from_=0, to=600)
br2= Scale(root,from_=0, to=600)

cans = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

def creat():
    cans.create_line(ar1.get(), ar2.get(), br1.get(), br2.get())
psy=Button(root, command=creat, text="karole")
ar1.pack()
ar2.pack()
br1.pack()
br2.pack()
psy.pack()
cans.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

A couple of other fixes: the `defaultvar` option is not valid and caused an error; `mainloop()` instead of `root.mainloop()` caused tk to create a second `Tk` object, which is a bad idea.

EDIT: added the code that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thought mainloop() would work, and i thought that ar1,ar2,... would have been stored as integers. I appreciate your help.